# I was wondering how I could make this work

Tags: python

```
name = raw_input("Hello sir! What is your name?")
print ("Nice to meet you " + name + "! Where were you born?")
born = input(" ")
print ("So your name is " + name + " and you were born in " + born + "!")
```

> And im getting the error " Nice to meet you  Will! Where were you born?
>        Florida
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/Users/39.cr/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 3, in 
>       born = input(" ")
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       NameError: name 'Florida' is not defined "

Comment: `input` should be `raw_input` in both cases in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use raw_input('') to get the born place name as well because you are using Python 2. On Python 3 your code would work. The reason is that in Python 2 you need to use raw_input() in order to get a string and not other object type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name = raw_input("Hello sir! What is your name?")
born = raw_input("Nice to meet you " + name + "! Where were you born?")
print("So your name is " + name + " and you were born in " + born + "!")
```